# How we can design a popup XML file?

Tags: android, android-xml

Here's my code for the XML file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="130dip"
 android:id="@+id/llll"
android:layout_height="200dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/limyprofile"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opmyprofile"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:clickable="true"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:maxHeight="40dip"
       android:maxWidth="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/myprofileimg" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/myprofiletxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:clickable="true"

    android:text="My Profile" />

 </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/lijobalert"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opjobalert"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
          android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/jobalert4" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/opjobalerttxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Job Alert" />

 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/lisavedjob"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opsavedjob"
          android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/jobapplied" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/savedtxt"
      android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Saved Jobs" />

 </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  
         android:id="@+id/liback" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back1" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/backtxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back" />

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/listlogout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/oplogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logout" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/logouttxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add a popup menu in my XML file as shown below :

[image]

How can a popup menu like this be created using XML?

Comment: Y dont you use **ListView** ??

Comment: i am new in android and listview is defficult for me so i used simple xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

[Android ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/xml_profilepopup"
    android:layout_width="257px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/homepopup"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5px"
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingRight="5px" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xml_logoutpopup_qa_rltvview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/qa_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/qaicn"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qa_txtview"
            style="@style/Common_view_medium_font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qa_img"
            android:text="@string/logout_qa" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/common_border_color" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xml_logoutpopup_training_rltvview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/xml_logoutpopup_training_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/trainingicn"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/xml_logout_training_txtview"
            style="@style/Common_view_medium_font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/xml_logoutpopup_training_img"
            android:text="@string/logout_training" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/xml_logout_today_training_txtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:background="@color/green_color"
       android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="2px"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/white" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/common_border_color" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xml_logoutpopup_daily_sync_rltvview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/daily_sync_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/qaicn"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/daily_sync_txtview"
            style="@style/Common_view_medium_font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/daily_sync_img"
            android:text="@string/logout_daily_sync" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/common_border_color" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xml_logoutpopup_change_passowrd_rltvview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/change_passowrd_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/changepassicn"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chngePass_txtview"
            style="@style/Common_view_medium_font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/change_passowrd_img"
            android:text="@string/logout_change_pwd" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/common_border_color" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/common_border_color" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xml_logoutpopup_logout_rltvview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logout_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/logouticn"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logout_txtview"
            style="@style/Common_view_medium_font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logout_img"
            android:text="@string/logout_logout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

please replace your image instead of my image...if any query then tell me...i hope its useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(this);
settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_layout
    , null));
settingsDialog.show();
```

on the xml side

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/fullimage" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/custom_fullimage_placename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made one of your item of popup you can repeat it by copy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/limyprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opmyprofile"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:maxHeight="40dip"
            android:maxWidth="40dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myprofiletxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="My Profile"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for replay bro, also i want to set line to another layout then how we can add plz suggest me

Comment: line between linear layout

Comment: see my updated answer and repeat linearlayout and view as per your need